# Converting Linux machine from XenServer to Hyper-V VM

Tags: linux, hyper-v, xenserver

I have a XenServer on a physical machine and I want to put it into my Hyper-V environment as a VM. Is this Possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what the *ovf/ova* format is for (*ova* is just an *ovf* image inside a *tar* file).

You can export your VM in an *ova* format [following these instructions](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xencenter/6-1/xs-xc-vms-exportimport/xs-xc-vms-export-ovf.html), and you can import them into Microsoft HyperV by using [Kensho](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2009/09/10/project-kensho-ovf-tool-hyper-v/). Kensho has been incorporated into Xenserver 5.6 and later, and its functionality (not its name) has been rolled into XenCenter and XenConvert. So, in line of principle, if you run a reasonably recent version of Xenserver, you should be able to do it all from within Xen. If you need help, read [this Citrix forum thread](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/287440-cannot-download-kensho-ovf-tool/), and possibly more posts within the same forum.

Importing *ova* into HyperV requires a dedicated tool because Microsoft does not follow widely agreed-upon open-source standards (God forbid!). But some generous soul (once again Citrix) provided a tool to allow importing  ova into HyperV.